# Fisher-Yates Shuffle : random if halted after m times?

Tags: random, shuffle

I have integers 1,2,3,...,n from which I have to pick m < n distinct integers randomly. I intend to put these integers in an array, and then use the Fisher Yates Shuffle:

Randomly pick an entry in the array. Swap it with the last entry. Then, randomly pick an entry in the array except for the last entry. Swap this with the 2nd last entry. Repeat until the last m entries were obtained this way.

**Question**

My understanding is that if continued until n times, every possible arrangement is equally likely with this shuffle. So, if halted after m < n times, every single arrangement of the last m entries are equally likely. Hence, the last m entries are the m random distinct integers I need.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. (This answer is even shorter than the length requirement to post a comment....)

Comment: You have just reinvented [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: @finnw - Nice link. Thanks for pointing it out. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, perhaps easier to go forward:

Let `rand(z)` return in range `[0..z)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    swap(X[i], X[i+rand(n-i)])
```

`X[0..m-1]` is now random sample